# How to Auto Scroll to Listview Item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

my question is simple. What i want to do is click on a hyperlink (item2 as diagram below), and my page will automatically scroll into (item2 content at the right side). Usually what we do is we set an id to the section, and put <#id> on the hyperlink it will have the scrolling feature. How about if the right hand side content is created as listviewitem? 
something like this: http://html5up.net/prologue

[image]

Comment: can you provide some html generated by listview?

Answer (score 0):

On click of item2, set the focus to Item2 from listview.

Comment: It can be easily done on static webpage but i have no idea how to make it on a dynamic listview.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question is not cleared.So it may help you..like Put the listview items in a panel.And add a style to panel.. `overflow:scroll;`

In css you can also apply this.